# failed to use mutt to send mail to company mailbox

Tags: postfix, mutt

I'm using mutt & postfix on CentOS 6.2:

- mutt-1.5.20-2.20091214hg736b6a.el6_1.1.x86_64
- postfix-2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.x86_64

When I try to send mail to my company mailbox, I receive an error:

```
mutt -s "test" myname@example.com < /home/mail.txt
```

Error from postfix:

```
<myname@example.com>: host out1.example.com[10.30.17.100] said: 
555 Syntax error (in reply to MAIL FROM command)


Then I try to use service sendmail as SMTP server, but also failed：

   **----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<myname@example.com>
    (reason: 555 Syntax error)
   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to out1.example.com.:
>>> MAIL From:<root@my_server> SIZE=667
<<< 555 Syntax error
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable**
```

I can make sure DNS is OK, and I set realname "root@myserver" in /etc/Muttrc

Any body can tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

Your company mail server has annouced (after `EHLO`) that they support **SMTP Service Extension for Message Size Declaration** defined in [RFC 1870](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1870.txt). Because of it, postfix and mutt will add string `SIZE=XXX` in the end of `MAIL FROM` line.

```
>>> MAIL From:<root@my_server> SIZE=667
```

Unfortunately, your mail server complain with error because *it seems they don't understand `SIZE` syntax.*

```
<<< 555 Syntax error
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a local MUA,which may be configured in a myriad of ways, start by using **telnet**:

```
$telnet 127.0.0.1 25
>HELO me.at.home
>MAIL FROM: me@home
>RCPT TO: some@where.else
>DATA
>Subject: Test
>foobar
>.
```

Then report what that says, and post the logs of the transaction.